# Tornado set minmum and maximum values for get_argument

Tags: python, python-2.7, tornado

I am currently using Tornado RequestHandler.get_argument to get http POST and GET arguments.
The RequestHandler.get_argument lets you set default values. Is there a way in Tornado
Is there is a way to set maximum and minimum values of GET and POST argument in tornado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use a simple if statement?

For example, if your minimum acceptable value is `7` and the maximum acceptable value is `47` you could write:

```
def post(self):
    my_arg = self.get_argument('my_arg')
    if not 7 <= my_arg <= 47:
        raise tornado.web.HTTPError(400)  # 400 Bad Request
```

If you are doing this a lot, you might try overriding the method, such as:

```
class MyHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):

    def get_argument(self, name, minimum, maximum):
        argument = super(MyHandler, self).get_argument(name)
        if not minimum <= argument <= maximum:
            raise tornado.web.HTTPError(400)  # 400 Bad Request
        return argument

    def post(self):
        small_arg = self.get_argument('small_arg', 1, 3)
        medium_arg = self.get_argument('medium_arg', 7, 47)
        large_arg = self.get_argument('large_arg', 9001, 10000)
```

Feel free to select a different [HTTP Status Code](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html).